# Implement git clone command in boot2DockerstartGit code meet issue

Tags: git, boot2docker

When I try to implement below command in boot2Dockerstart:
$ git clone git@github.com:aspnet/Home.git aspnet-Home

I got below error response:
Cloning into 'aspnet-Home'...
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '192.30.252.128' to t
he list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

The error seems pretty clear ("Permission denied (publickey).").  You are trying to clone a git repository using ssh, which requires git to have access to the corresponding private key.

If this is a public repository, just replace the repository url with the `http:` or `https:` url (which you can find on github).

If it's a private repository, you either need to make your private key available to git, or you need to set up a [deploy key](https://github.com/blog/2024-read-only-deploy-keys) to permit access to this particular repository (and provide *that* corresponding private key to git).

Comment: Iarsks, thank you, I use below way can resolve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "forwhat.cn" // "forwaht.cn" it is your ACCOUNT in GitHub

then terminal will show:
Generating public/private rsa key pair. 
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/forwhat.cn/.ssh/id_rsa):

please press Enter button if you use the default path.

Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): //please press Enter button.
Enter same passphrase again://please press Enter button again.
The message will show:Your identification has been saved in /home/forwhat.cn/.ssh/id_rsa. 
Your public key has been saved in /home/forwhat.cn/.ssh/id_rsa.pub. 
The key fingerprint is:*******************

now, please use cat command to output the key results:
cat /home/forwhat.cn/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

then copy it and login GitBub to setup the SHH setting, then the issue be resolved.